# Using "en" to replace part of subject

Tags: pronoms, compléments, en, sujet

The pronoun "en" can be used to replace a phrase "de ...", as in

> Tu es le meilleur joueur de l'équipe.
>
> Tu en es le meilleur joueur.

Can we also use "en" to replace a phrase if the phrase is part of the subject of the sentence?

> Le meilleur joueur de l'équipe est Pierre.
>
> Le meilleur joueur en est Pierre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are correct.

In [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en#Pronom_personnel) :

- > 3. (Remplaçant un nom avec de dans le COD, **dans le sujet** de la copule ou dans l’attribut)

Do you have another question?